Wobbly divisor in the moduli space of rank 2 degree 1semi-stable vector bundles over a curve of genus 2
I am looking at Nigel Hitchin's lecture "Higgs fields in low genus" on the occasion of Oscar Garcia-Prada's 60th birthday. In the rank 2 odd degree case, he mentions a map $f$ from the moduli space to $\mathbb{P}^3$, and claims that the wobbly divisor is the inverse image of the discriminant sextic surface. I don't understand this map clearly. I know that the wobbly divisor in this case has just one component, and I have some intuition as to why points on the discriminant sextic must map to wobbly bundles, but I can't work out the details. One intuition is to consider the matrix form of the Higgs field. Since, the Higgs field is nonzero nilpotent for wobbly bundles, the matrix is strictly upper triangular. Can I just naively map entries in the matrix form of Higgs field to the projective space and argue that the inverse image of the discriminant sextic is wobbly? Another intuition could be using spectral curves, but then how do we get cubic equations to connect them with the sextic, we might only get quadratic equations?
